# Can I set a nested attribute in the controller vs. the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have a simple nested form and I am setting a nested attribute with a hidden field:

```
<%= role_form.hidden_field :company_id, :value => session[:company_id] %>
```

The idea here is I am associating this nested model (a role based permissions system) to another model `Company` via the `company_id` set by the current session variable.  My issue is that the user could send a request and create / update the role with an arbitrary `company_id` and gain access to another company's account.

Can I force the nested model attributes to be this session value or perhaps a validation?

I was thinking for create:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.roles.first.company_id = session[:company_id]
```

and for update I could do sort of the same thing.

As for the validation I tried:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, :limit => 1, :allow_destroy => true , :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['company_id'] != session[:company_id] }`

but it looks like you can't access the session info in the model.

Any one have an idea if I can do this either of these ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than storing the company_id in the session, you should instead add a randomly generated token column to the company, and get the id by doing Company.find_by_token(session[:token]). If you look at how the current_user method in [this Railscast on authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1), it's the same idea.

Edit:
Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You should not have a hidden company_id field at all in your view. You should be setting it manually in your create method:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.company_id = session[:company_id]
```

And you can protect the company_id from ever being set from the user changing an input name by having company_id protected against mass assignment in the model:

```
attr_protected :company_id
```

See the [rails guide on mass assignment protection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) for more information. Note: a more common solution is something along these lines:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  def current_company
    @current_company ||= Company.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  end
end

class User < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = current_company.users.build(params[:user])
  end
end
```

UPDATE 2:

So you're creating a user and a role, and want to do separate validation on them, this should do what you want.

```
role_params = params[:user].delete :role # Change to the appropriate symbol for your form
@user = User.new(params[:user])
role = @user.roles.build(role_params)
role.company_id = session[:company_id]

if(@user.save and role.user_id = @user.id and role.save) # Might want to just check for valid instead of trying to save
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That is probably a good idea but that still doesn't solve my issue. Currently a user could mass assign another company_id and access another company's account. Its not likely this would ever happen I just see it as a glaring security hole.

Comment: I have updated my answer to more appropriately answer your question. It looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel on mass assignment protection when it's already built into rails! Gave examples on how to handle this, and a link to the official rails guide on the subject.

Comment: Ok. I get what you are saying. I am actually using that Railscast in this app. I think attr_protected is my solution. The remaining issue is that the company_id is not set on the User but on the nested Role. I have a system where a single user login (email) can have access to multiple Company models via the Role. Each Role has a user_id and a company_id. The user_id gets set automatically in the nested form but I need to manually set the company_id. I am at a loss how to do this as the accepts_nested_attributes seems to do it via magic.

Comment: Here is another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011479/how-to-pass-session-variable-to-model-in-ror that seems be on a similar thread. The merge call might be the answer but in my case I need to validate / update the params(:role) data for the nested form.

Comment: You do it the same way, just have the attr_protected on role, and set it via the controller -- @user.roles.first or however you're selecting the role .company_id = session[:company_id]. You might also want to consider having the user and role tables updated from separate pages so you can control this more granularly.

Comment: Updating to respond to your second comment

Comment: I've added code that would allow you to handle the user and role separately. This really does sound like a case where the role should be created first, however.

Comment: I implemented your solution (however a bit differently) as I think it's really the only way to do this.