# Ruby on rails passing information from session into db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I have been trying to set up a little twitter app to teach myself ruby on rails, i have a log in page that works and stores the user like this

```
    session[:user_id] = user.id
```

I can use that in the views, but i am trying to create a relationship based on it so that the tweet, which is created on a new page in in a basic form, is linked to the current session user.

I for some reason can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011479/how-to-pass-session-variable-to-model-in-ror

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `current_user` (for example) method:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end
```

If you already have this, you can create post with:

```
@post = current_user.posts.create(params[:post])
```

You should also check, of course, if any user is signed in before creating post, or you'll have `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 0):

See devise gem https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
Devise provided current_user and user_session methods in your views and controllers